# How to remove double currency symbol apear on currency conversion in wordpress e-commerce site?

Tags: wordpress

Project Link: http://barrelpackers4u.com/

I have to remove double currency symbol appear after choosing currency conversion. I am using e-Commerce Multi Currency plugin with wp-ecommerce.

In left sidebar there is currency select widget it is working fine but repeat currency symbol after successful conversion [ see product price ].

Have tried removing using jQuery [ remove repeated string ] but I do not want it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-e-commerce-multi-currency-magic-currency-sign-bug) posts seems to have the solution to your problem. Also try updating your software version